# Hardware list for wardriving(pen testing) with an rpi2 and laptop

Tags: networking, wifi, hardware, raspberry-pi2

so basically I've been online trying to research this the whole day and I seem to only be able to come across specific setups that people have for their own specific needs rather than a generic list of hardware needed.

What I want to do firstly using my raspberry pi 2 running raspbian, and secondly a laptop running kali, is to be able to do penetration testing along with some extras.
What I Am looking for is a list of hardware that I need (other than the rpi2 for the first case and laptop for the second) that will enable me to sniff out WiFi signals,  and attempt to get onto the network. I believe the general name for this is wardriving.

I know that I need a portable power supply for the rpi2, and a screen or some sort (I want a small screen that I can see the rpi gui desktop from. Not just terminal), so any suggestions of examples of those would be appreciated.

Where I get confused is about the WiFi antenna that I need.  From what I understand is that it needs to be one that can monitor as well as connect to a WiFi,  but I don't really know of any examples or of what the actual difference is between it and a normal usb WiFi stick.

I'm also not sure what else I need to have beyond that to successfully accomplish my stated goal.

Any further help would be greatly appreciated,  and I think beneficial to anyone else who's looking to get started doing the same thing.

Any extra information would be good too   what I mean is when I was doing my research I saw some people mentioning radio attachments,  gps attachments, etc. But I'm not really sure if they're necessary to start or things that can be added further down the road with experience.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I seem to have found a good article that answers at least the general part of my question.  It can be found here.

http://lewiscomputerhowto.blogspot.ca/2014/06/how-to-hack-wpawpa2-wi-fi-with-kali.html?m=1

It also gives tips on the process of pen testing.

Comment: I mean,  it answers my question about the wireless card,  and antenna kind of.  So that being relative to pen testing with a laptop.  Still doesn't answer any of my questions regarding doing it with my rpi2.